# ChartJs title not showing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS version 2.6.0. and I'm having some difficulties with the 'title' option of the chart. It's simply not showing on the rendered chart.
I'm following the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html?h=title), and passing the title in as described:

```
var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'PLEASE DISPLAY FOR HEAVEN\'S SAKE'
    },
    responsive: true,
    bezierCurve: true,
    legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
    },
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 1,
    events: ['click']
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("chartId");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

However, the title simply wont show. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha19ozqy/89/) with a dougnut chart, that has the same issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe it is not supported in version 2. Use version 3/4 instead

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to wrap the `title` object inside an `options` object like

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'TEST'
            }
        }
    } 
....
```

Here are the docs for a full list of all the options, [chartjs:title](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html)

```js
var data = [2137680, 6282693, 805566, 2568163, 598599, 3189284, 599112, 926340, 5548295, 11847685, 66445];
var labels = ["Management", "Finance", "Human Resources", "Business Development and Marketing", "Information Technology", "Professional Development and Training", "Knowledge Management", "Logistics", "Support", "Business Services", "Other"];
var bgColor = ["#878BB6", "#FFEA88", "#FF8153", "#4ACAB4", "#c0504d", "#8064a2", "#772c2a", "#f2ab71", "#2ab881", "#4f81bd", "#2c4d75"];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'TEST'
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: bgColor
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unf4exa2/

Comment: AH, so an 'options' object INSIDE the 'options' object. Neat. :) Thanks a lot, man

Comment: Yep that's it, quite alright. The docs section of chartjs is really good if you come up against things like this in the future they normally have a nice example of whatever thing you are trying to do and is always my go-to when something doesn't work when i think it should.

Comment: I think what confused me was the nested option object. As you can see from my code, I instantiate my chart options as a seperate object, so I totally missed it from the docs. Thanks again

Comment: @MichaelCleverly IKR, the confusion arose because of the variable name of the object literal! It wouldn't have happened if the OP had chosen a more apt name, like "parameters" or "config"! Another case where the programmer's most difficult task is not algorithms or design patters, but NAMING! var fooBar = {foo:1, bar: 2};  xD

Answer (score 10):

You should import the Title first:

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, Title } from 'chart.js';
```

and then add your Tile to your Register:

```
ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, ChartDataLabels, Title);
```

finally use your title in options.plugins:

```
const options: any = {
plugins: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Your Title",
  },
}
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try adding options object inside for title

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaffreena/ha19ozqy/93/

```
var data = [2137680, 6282693, 805566, 2568163, 598599, 3189284, 599112, 926340, 5548295, 11847685, 66445];
var labels = ["Management", "Finance", "Human Resources", "Business Development and Marketing", "Information Technology", "Professional Development and Training", "Knowledge Management", "Logistics", "Support", "Business Services", "Other"];
var bgColor = ["#878BB6", "#FFEA88", "#FF8153", "#4ACAB4", "#c0504d", "#8064a2", "#772c2a", "#f2ab71", "#2ab881", "#4f81bd", "#2c4d75"];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',

    data: {

        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: bgColor
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Custom Chart Title'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the `title` object inside the `plugins` object and then `plugins` inside `options`.

Version: 3.7.1

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    options: {
      plugins:{
         title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Title'
            }
        }
    }
```

This will surely work!

Comment: this works with the latest version 3.7.1

Comment: @Francisco Thx I have added the version in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `title` property should come inside another property called `options`. Try this.

```
options : {
title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'TITLE HERE'
    }
}
```

You can check for some examples [here](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSFiddle, you forgot to add `options`.

The example in the documentation is:

```
 options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Custom Chart Title'
        }
        },
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ha19ozqy/90/